# How can I use # in a var name. JSON, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, decodable

I am trying to use decodable to parse some json but one of the names in the json has a # in it.

How can I add this to my var like below?

```
"image": [
    { 
        "#text": "https…",
        "size": "small"
    },
```

Comment: Please post code as text (not images) so it is searchable

Comment: The image is from the Json not my code. it was showing the example of the #sign in the key.

Comment: JSON, code, error messages, crash logs, whatever.  Please post as text and not images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Swift variables must begin with either a letter or an underscore.

What you *can* do is add `CodingKeys` to translate between the field name in your JSON and the property in your object…

```
struct Image: Decodable {
    let text: String
    let size: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case text = "#text", size
    }
}
```

should do it

Comment: Thank you for this I had already created an enum the same way but made a seperate case for size and used URL instead of String in text. Your version worked fine for me with these changes thank you.